# Postgres - Get the count of each genre when the genre column has comma seperated values 'Action, Comedy,....Thriller...'

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table and the fourth Column contains the genres of each movie. What I want to achieve is to find the count of each genre.

```
"C6523" 1894    "f" "Documentary,Short"
"C4532" 1892    "f" "Animation,Short"
"P1616" 1892    "f" "Animation,Comedy,Romance"
"B512"  1892    "f" "Animation,Short"
"B4253" 1893    "f" "Comedy,Short"
"C5215" 1894    "f" "Short"
"C6135" 1894    "f" "Short,Sport"
"E3252" 1894    "f" "Documentary,Short"
```

Expected Output:

```
Animation : 12300..
Comedy: 5000...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Sub Query`

```
SELECT "MovieGenres", COUNT("MovieGenres")
FROM (
       SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array(subject, ',')) as "MovieGenres" FROM Table
     ) X
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Final Query for my case: SELECT "MovieGenres", COUNT("MovieGenres")
FROM 
(
 SELECT UNNEST(string_to_array(genres, ',')) as "MovieGenres" FROM title_basics
) as HelpingTable GROUP BY "MovieGenres";

Comment: You can simplify that to: `from table, unnest(...) as movie_genres` no derived table required.